# Dynamic prototype cell height size of UITableViewController on storyboard

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, prototype

I've realized that if I use Static cell option on the storyboard, 
UITableViewController control the height of itself, so there's no problem when we use it.

But if we use Dynamic prototype cells, and if we make different height of cells, the tableview on storyboard couldn't catch it, 
so the result of contentsSize of tableview would be different.

I solved this problem with UITableViewDelegate method below but it seems stupid:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Is there any other smart way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is the **correct/best** way to establish a custom height for a cell in a `UITableViewController`.

It has some performance problems when table view is large (>1k rows), but it gives you the flexibility to dynamically change the height of your cells and make a prettier user interface.